# HTTP Status 405 - Request method 'POST' not supported when I upgrade from Spring 3.0.5.RELEASE to Spring 3.1.0.M1

Tags: spring

I encounter the error:

> HTTP Status 405 - Request method 'POST' not supported

when I upgrade from Spring 3.0.5.RELEASE to Spring 3.1.0.M1. There is no other change in my code, what can be the reason? The code is something like:

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String create(@Valid ConcreteUser concreteUser, BindingResult bindingResult, Model uiModel, HttpServletRequest request)
```

When I switch back to Spring 3.0.5.RELEASE, it is working again. However I still desire to upgrade my Spring library to 3.1.0.M1 since I may want to use its new Cacheable feature etc. How to achieve the upgrade without any problem?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a spring bug (if you use google you will find some problems like that with 3.1 pre release version).
But first of all, use the actual 3.1 version. At the moment it is 3.1.RC2 (http://www.springsource.org/node/3317) -- Hopefully the bug is gone.

Comment: Thank you Ralph, I will give it a try since the actual 3.1 version is just released.

Comment: I have just tried the latest Spring release 3.1 (release yesterday): <spring.version>3.1.0.RELEASE</spring.version>, but the same problem still exist. I will keep my research on this issue.